# Listview Column resize

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My listview columns seem to be REALLY small; the words don't seem to fit.

[image]

But I would like for it to spell the word out completely instead of split it into different lines.

Is there a setting I'm missing?

```
    private void checklog (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:/Users/sisson.chad/Documents/logs/BatchProcessor.20170116151505106.log"))
        {
            string contents = sr.ReadToEnd();
            if (contents.Contains("getDownloadFileList failed"))
            {
                listView5.Items.Add("Lost Connection.");
                listView6.Items.Add("Remove block file and run script.");

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can we see some code??

Comment: added code!!! sorry about that.

Comment: Is this Windows forms? or WPF?

Comment: Yes @lexWebb i grabbed it from the toolbox in VS

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the `Columns` property from each of the `ListView`s first. Then, set the `Width` to `-2`. This will autosize the column to the length of the text in the column header.

Example:

```
foreach (var columnHeader in ListView.Columns.Cast<ColumnHeader>())
{
    columnHeader.Width = -2;
}
```

You can make this a method, and pass the `ListView` as the parameter.

Also. You can remove the cast by declaring the class in the loop

```
foreach (ColumnHeader columnHeader in ListView.Columns)
{
    columnHeader.Width = -2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/EXL69zE.png I tried to do this already and it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.. maybe I am adding it wrong

Comment: Why do you have two listviews?

Comment: Try running it after you add the items.

Comment: I have it in two different sections, the one of the left shows the error, the one on the right shows the solution to the error

Comment: Change the width after you add the items. Also, add a check before the `Add` to not add the string to the listview if its already there

Comment: oh yeah i already know that, I'm just testing column width atm

Comment: Did you change the width at the end of the process?

Comment: yeah i added it after and it still isn't making it bigger

Comment: Is this winforms?

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing there buddy. Try different values for the width. But, you should not get so many columns unless you are adding them in a different place that you are not showing here

Comment: I can't try that code. But, one thing that I see is that you are not using the method `autoResizeColumns(ListView lv)` anywhere

Comment: Yes I've removed it because it wasn't doing anything =\

Comment: Of course! you have to add columns before being able to change the width! 

   `listView1.Columns.Add("TEST", 500, HorizontalAlignment.Left);`